# A simple jQuery accordion not working, help needed

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, slidetoggle

My skills in javascript in jQuery extends only to "cut&paste"-coding, and I would appreciate some help with A) get this simple accordion to work properly B) if possible clean it up a bit. Maybe a class is not needed on each H3 etc.

When clicking any H3 to expand the corresponding div with text, ALL of them are opened. I would of course only want them to open one at a time.

Here is the non-working codepen:
http://codepen.io/tuleby/pen/ijqHL

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="workposts">
            <h3 class="toggle-trigger">2014-06-05<span>Heading A</span></h3>
            <div class="toggle-content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
                </p>
            </div>

            <h3 class="toggle-trigger">2014-06-04<span>Heading B</span></h3>
            <div class="toggle-content">
                <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                </p>
            </div>

            <h3 class="toggle-trigger">2014-05-19<span>Heading C</span></h3>
            <div class="toggle-content">
                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam
                </p>
            </div>

            <h3 class="toggle-trigger">2014-05-19<span>Heading D</span></h3>
            <div class="toggle-content">
                <p>Lquis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit </p>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $('.workposts').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.toggle-content').hide();
    });

    $('.workposts h3.toggle-trigger').click(function(){
        var el = $(this), parent = el.closest('.workposts');

        if( el.hasClass('active') )
        {
            parent.find('.toggle-content').slideToggle();
            el.removeClass('active');
        }
        else
        {
            parent.find('.toggle-content').slideToggle();
            el.addClass('active');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You didn't include the jQueryUI library and all of the associated CSS.

Comment: Sorry @krillgar, I made an error when pasting the code above, the jquery link was not included at first but i edited shortly after posting. As to the CSS it is not relevant for the functionality but you can see it in the Codepen. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of the parent element seems to be the problem

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.workposts .toggle-content').hide();

    $('.workposts h3.toggle-trigger').click(function () {
        var el = $(this);

        el.toggleClass('active');
        el.next('.toggle-content').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6n7sT/)

Comment: Out of interest, why would you not use the `.accordion()` in the *UI library*?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) like this...

```
$(function() {
    $( ".workposts" ).accordion();
  });
```

by including the Jquery UI library

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I updated your [*CodePen*](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AFnxa) too.